# rake db:migrate gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, sqlite, database-migration

I just tried to migrate, but my console returns this

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: encrypted_password:
>   ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT
>   NULL

I understand that I accidentally created a table twice and have to do changes in my migration file? If so, where can I find it?
Dropping the whole database would be a good solution, too in my case.

I just need to know how. All the solutions I found so far didn't work for me.

UPDATE:
When I do

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20160914093125

The console says

> == 20160914093125 DeviseCreateUsers: reverting ================================
>   -- remove_index(:users, {:column=>:reset_password_token})    -> 0.0013s
>   -- remove_index(:users, {:column=>:email})    -> 0.0006s
>   -- drop_table(:users)    -> 0.0003s
>   == 20160914093125 DeviseCreateUsers: reverted (0.0025s) =======================

Are these the points i should change?

**3123(...)devise_create_user.rb**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Console after trying to migrate:

> == 20160915185631 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
>   -- change_table(:users)
>   rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`new'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in`execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `block in execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in`block in log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in`log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in`add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in `add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:475:in`column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in `block in string'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in`each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in `string'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in`block in up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in `change_table'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in`block in method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:596:in`method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:751:in`up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `exec_migration'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in`with_connection'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in`within_new_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in`transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`block (2 levels) in '
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`initialize'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`prepare'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in`block in execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in`execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in `add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in`add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:475:in `column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in`block in string'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in `each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in`string'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in`change_table'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`block in say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in`method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:596:in `method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in`up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:751:in `up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in`exec_migration'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in`block in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in`block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in`block in transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in`transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in`block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in`up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in`'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`new'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in`execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `block in execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in`block in log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in`log'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `execute'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:547:in`add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:373:in `add_column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:475:in`column'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in `block in string'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in`each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:181:in `string'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in`block in up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:443:in `change_table'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in`block in method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in`say_with_time'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:596:in`method_missing'
/Users/matthiascordes/code/recipe_box/db/migrate/20160915185631_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:751:in`up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:791:in `exec_migration'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in`with_connection'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in`block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in`within_new_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in`transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in`each'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1133:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in`migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`block (2 levels) in '
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

Comment: Its not the duplicate table, its because you are adding a duplicate column. If you wish to change the column default try to use change column default.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the migration file, which you want to revert back, then use this,

```
For eg, if this is the migration file,
20123219103503_add_name_field_to_user.rb
```

then copy the numbers in the file and then run the following in your terminal prompt,

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20123219103503
```

make editions in the migration files, then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

from terminal

Comment: All right, how would I do the editions (see question update). Sorry, but I am new to rails

Comment: That's fine. Everyone is new to something always. No worries. You added any new additions to the default migration which comes with the devise. I  meant you added any new attributes?

Comment: It seems that you made no change with the devise migration. Did u add any new migrations for user, which has encrypted_password in it?

Comment: if not, then can you just run rake db:migrate from your terminal, and see if still the error exists?

Comment: I went into the direction db/migrate and deleted all files relating to user and now just create a new user model. hope that will work. thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have modified the database schema manually or changed a migration file being run.

If you dont need the data in the database, a `rake db:reset` would re-run all migrations from scratch.

You could also try to migrate your database to version 0 with command: `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` and then run `rake db:migrate`

---

If you want to drop the whole database as you stated, you can do either of the following:

> `rake db:drop` simply drops the whole database.
>
> `rake db:reset db:migrate` will reset your database and reload the
>   current schema.
>
> `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` will destroy your database and
>   then create it and then migrate your current schema.

All data will be lost in the above 3 scenarios.

---

You could also comment out the method in the migration file, then run `rake db:migrate` as below:

Normal Migration File:

```
class AddEncryptedPaddwordToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :encrypted_password, :string
  end
end
```

Just comment out the method but leave the class, so it would be:

```
class AddEncryptedPaddwordToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # def change
  #   add_column :users, :encrypted_password, :string
  # end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`. Essentially this is a work around that tells rails to skip the migration

Comment: Doing rake:reset or reake:drop gives me: 
rake aborted! ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError:
Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run:
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: Are you using rails 5?